# Debugging initializer in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, development-environment, stripe-payments, production

I'm debugging a stripe payments initializer in rails.  I want it to notify me if the current environment is the production environment so I can see if Stripe is getting the right keys.  How would you use an initializer to print to the console or put information in a view?

**Edit - Here's the initializer**

```
if Rails.env.production?
  Rails.configuration.stripe = {
    publishable_key: ENV[ 'PUBLISHABLE_KEY' ],
    secret_key:      ENV[ 'SECRET_KEY' ]
  }
else
  Rails.configuration.stripe = {
    publishable_key: 'pk_test_UQ2EqhNNQRrDkD5V0Z1xgpS5',
    secret_key:      'sk_test_hkiYUTQzHiCTBfHuUSXpUP7n'
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm using Heroku.  Running

```
heroku run console
```

runs a console in Heroku and

```
Rails.env
```

returns the environment.

Comment: I don't understand, this is an answer?

Comment: @DaveNewton although this wasn't the original way I was thinking of accomplishing the task, this returns the environment so I know that the environment is not a problem.

Comment: But you're doing that in your original code; I don't understand still.

Comment: The code in the post does not tell me if it is production or development, because evaluating either could cause the error I was getting.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily print to the log in the initializer:

```
Rails.logger.info "in special initializer"
```

You can then check the logs with `heroku logs` to watch for the log message.